# xamarin forms get a value from ResourceDictionary

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have 2 different values for the Left Margin and the Right Margin for my application. (Let say 27 and 64)

Is it possible to get these values from the ResourcesDictionaty and set them in my XAML.

For example

```
<StackLayout Margin="{Left1},0,{Right1},0">
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify them as double values in `ResourceDictionary` and refer to them in other resources/styles or at element level itself.

**Sample resource-dictionary**

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <!-- namespace declaration 
          xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime" -->
    <sys:Double x:Key="leftMargin">20</sys:Double>
    <sys:Double x:Key="rightMargin">30</sys:Double>

    <Thickness x:Key="MyMargin1" 
        Left="{StaticResource leftMargin}" 
        Right="{StaticResource rightMargin}" 
        Top="20"
        Bottom="30" />

    <Thickness x:Key="MyMargin2" 
        Left="{StaticResource leftMargin}" 
        Right="{StaticResource rightMargin}" 
        Top="5"
        Bottom="15" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Sample usage**

```
<StackLayout>

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="{StaticResource MyMargin1}" />

    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Black" />

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="{StaticResource MyMargin2}" />

    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Black" />

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Yellow">
        <BoxView.Margin>
            <Thickness
                Left="{StaticResource leftMargin}" 
                Right="{StaticResource rightMargin}" 
                Top="30"
                Bottom="10" />
        </BoxView.Margin>
    </BoxView>

    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Black" />
</StackLayout>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That is Perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think doing this for individual values will work. You can however bind the entire `Margin` to a value in a resource dictionary as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Thickness x:Key="MyMargin">27,0,64,0</Thickness>
</ResourceDictionary>

<StackLayout Margin="{StaticResource MyMargin}">
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: That will set also the top margin and the bottom margin! I don't want that!

Comment: Then set those to 0. That should achieve what you're looking for shouldn't it?

Comment: I don't think that you understood what I'm asking for. I have 10 controls (for example) on my page. The first has margin 20,1,20,4 the second, 20,12,20,5 the third... all of them have the same left and right margin but not the same top and bottom margin. The same thing happens to all the pages of the application. Your solution is fix left right, bottom, top for everything. I don;t want that.

Comment: I didn't understand that because your original question doesn't specify it... Either way putting individual `Margin` values in a resource dictionary is not possible. What's the reason you want to separate the top/bottom and left/right margins into 2 separate locations namely the Resource Dictionary and inline markup?

Comment: I did specify it in the example `Margin="{Left1},0,{Right1},0"`, Left and Right as parameters. The reason is that the Left and Right Margin is the same in the entire application so I would like to specify it only once and if I want to change in the future, to change it only in one place.